# macOS turn off spatial audio

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, airpods, apple-silicon

I "upgraded" to macOS 12.5 and now my AirPods Pro turned on spatial audio (when connected to my MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon). This is making me dizzy how do I turn it off?

Comment: Does [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212182) help?

Comment: Thank you, I do not have the Music app

Comment: Click on the AirPods icon in the menu bar (while connected) - does the option show up there? Otherwise check [control center](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211775#Mac).

Comment: Does your Mac have Apple Silicon? Pretty sure Spatial Audio is limited to those Macs.

Comment: Yes I do..........

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I've clarified that in your question. Did my suggestion allow you to turn off Spatial Audio?